# mySQL column returns colum name insted of values

Tags: mysql, identity-column

I have this problem that select returns the name of the column insted of the values in it. I have no idea what's causing that behavious.

Upper table is the result i get and lower table is the whole table that i would like to get a part of. Insted the 0's in wys are replaced with string wys and my script doesnt work because of this query

[image]

Comment: You are mixing backticks (`\``) with single quotes (`'`). Single quotes denote a literal string, backticks delimit an identifier. So, use `\`wys\``, not `'wys'`.

Comment: Dlaczego masz `index` na prawej stronie?

Comment: Just gotta love the unnecessary backticks. My personal preference is to use a table alias... (e.g. `SELECT p.oceana, p.wys FROM POSTY p ` ). If you code that way, and you accidentally use the wrong quotes around a column name, MySQL will throw an error, rather than returning a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

You're using regular quotes on wys, indicating a string literal;

```
'wys'
```

instead of - as you do on the other columns - backticks which indicate a table column name;

```
`ocena`
```

which makes MySQL use the *string literal* `wys` instead of the contents of the *table column* `wys` as a result for that result column in the query.

Comment: Cant belive this i spent 2 hours looking inside phpadmin looking for answers. Your the best

Answer (score 1):

You should change your SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT `zdjecie`, `opis`, `tekst`, `ocena`, `wys`
  FROM POSTY
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''POSTY' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: what's that single quote doing there?